# How can I use my NoSQL Workbench table schema into aws cli dynamodb create-table locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

So, I have a table that I created in NoSQL workbench. NoSQL workbench allows me to export the table to either a Workbench JSON or a CloudFormation JSON.

I want to use either one of these options to create my table using aws cli.

**This is because I want to create a database using my docker container and run my tests against it, then delete the table. The table is recreated on each test, then deleted again. So I need a way to create a fresh table everytime. So I would accept any other solution to achieve the same. This is just the one that I found to be less verbose**

This is a table .json that I want to import into aws cli:

https://gist.github.com/pedrohba1/59d75fc18156091cc085a2a6de4417fb

The idea is to use this command to create the table in the link:

```bash
DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT='http://localhost:8001'
aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://table.json --endpoint-url $DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT
```

However, it complains of a bunch of errors when doing it:

```
Missing required parameter in input: "AttributeDefinitions"
Missing required parameter in input: "TableName"
Missing required parameter in input: "KeySchema"
Unknown parameter in input: "AWSTemplateFormatVersion", must be one of: AttributeDefinitions, TableName, KeySchema, LocalSecondaryIndexes, GlobalSecondaryIndexes, BillingMode, ProvisionedThroughput, StreamSpecification, SSESpecification, Tags, TableClass
Unknown parameter in input: "Resources", must be one of: AttributeDefinitions, TableName, KeySchema, LocalSecondaryIndexes, GlobalSecondaryIndexes, BillingMode, ProvisionedThroughput, StreamSpecification, SSESpecification, Tags, TableClass
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The generated CF template cannot be used as is with the AWS CLI. You will need to remove the CF specific objects. See revised code snippet in the comment. Although it would be good for the tool to generate one where the cli can consume w/out changes.

you can use the below to see the expected format.

```
aws dynamodb create-table --generate-cli-skeleton input > test.json
```

Comment: So, I could make a scipt that gets all the props in the expected format, and then delete all the unexpected props in my generated json? So it would be a valid json.